# Use nohup when server goes down?

Tags: ubuntu, nohup

I am running tests on my computer (I am using Ubuntu ), that take up to 30-45 minutes. When the server I am working with goes down(for any kind of reason), my tests stop and I have to redo every test from the begging. I was wondering whether using nohup will still keep the tests running when the server goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry .. nohup means "no hang up", essentially if you log out of your session, the process you've nohupped will carry on.  If you turn off the machine, all active processes are lost.